# When would you use filter health checks?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, health-monitoring, health-check

I was reading this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1#filter-health-checks and couldn't visualize a practical use case for using filter health checks. In a real world situation, when would I use this? Thanks!

Comment: If your api is big, you can make a filter on component to check by component is ok. But if you have architecture in micro-service, a simple heal-check on your service is adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same page you shared, you can see the following:

> Health probes can be used by container orchestrators and load balancers to check an app's status. For example, a container orchestrator may respond to a failing health check by halting a rolling deployment or restarting a container. A load balancer might react to an unhealthy app by routing traffic away from the failing instance to a healthy instance.
>
> Use of memory, disk, and other physical server resources can be monitored for healthy status.
>
> Health checks can test an app's dependencies, such as databases and external service endpoints, to confirm availability and normal functioning.

As you can see, there are multiple different types of health checks.

I can see two reasons:

1. Different reporting purposes

- Group items for specific monitoring client. One could be a systems division and one a database division

2. Performance reasons

- Assesing the health of the database might take time. You might need to raise these during the nighttime, while others every 5 minutes. Filtering will execute the proper ones.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So for different health checks to be available, I assume the developer would need to create different sets of checks and an endpoint for each set to trigger and check. Perhaps using [MapWhen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1#restrict-health-checks-with-mapwhen) along with Predicate to trigger different sets of checks? Does this sound correct? Definitely predetermined and pre-built sets of health checks and not created on the fly, right?

Comment: Quite right. It's all about the grouping and the purpose of each group.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple health check types that can be used. Most of them are mentioned in the link you provided.
Some of the more popular ones include checking database connection or if an endpoint is available.

As for a real life situation:

I add my services to kubernetes. In case you don't know what kubernetes is think of it as guy that is keeping track of my service. Now in kubernetes you can specify the endpoints of your health checks so kubernetes can gather information to what the state of your application is. kubernetes can be configured to do specific operations in relations to the status of your healthchecks.
For example kubernities asks for general healthcheck of your service. Lets say database connection and another service you communicate through endpoint. At some interval it gets a degraded(cant do what i need it to do) status because nothing is working. At that point I can precondition kubernities to shut down the service or restart it.

Now if you scale up the service to multiple services that communicate with each other and multiple databases. Then you can see how with kubernetes and healthchecks you can keep a good monitoring outlook of the entire system.
As you can imagine the complexity of some of the health checks scales up also.

This is a real life situation that takes place today with healthchecks on micro service systems. Really helpful.

I hope this helps you :D

Comment: Thanks for the response. So for different health checks to be available, I assume the developer would need to create different sets of checks and an endpoint for each set to trigger and check. Perhaps using [MapWhen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1#restrict-health-checks-with-mapwhen) along with Predicate to trigger different sets of checks? Does this sound correct? Definitely predetermined and pre-built sets of health checks and not created on the fly, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. MapWhen is one of the ways using it.
Nothing comes to mind as of healthchecks on the fly. But I guess that could be a case if you are depended on a third party service. Say you do something with weather data that you request all the time but for some reason you didn't get weather data but the server is responsive. But I am talking about extreme cases and even at that times you can pre built for it. Hope that helps man. Dont forget to upvote the answer if it helps you :D